# Cloud project not listed in Google Play Console > Play Game Service set up

Tags: android, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to start the Play Game Service and link it to the cloud project that I have created and enabled Google Play Developer api.

However, on 'Play Games Services setup' page, I can't locate my cloud project. Even if I put the exact project name, it is not in the search results.

On Cloud Platform, I verified that I'm the owner of the project.

[image]

Also, I'm confused about the Cloud project and Game Service project.

As far as I know, 1 developer account can be linked to 1 API project.

If I want to link my app to each game service projects and link my developer account to 1 cloud project, what should I do?

I'm trying to use reply to reviews api to my app. If I just add 'Google Play Developer api' to my game service project in Cloud platform, would it be okay?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it the following way ...

Open your project's Google Cloud Console and starting from main menu select

`APIs & Services > Library > Google Play Android Developer API` ... and click on button `Enable`.

Once you did that, refresh your Google Play Console. Your project should show up in the drop-down list.

Comment: It works! Thank you @Viktor!